# One page app doesn't refresh with Ajax and SQL requests (online only)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, caching

I'm trying to build a trip organiser. It's a one page app. There are a list of trips, with their activities on one side, and the Google Map on the other side.

Screenshot here : http://hpics.li/fc1b59c

I have two main files : one called `app.js`, where I trigger events with forms and click on buttons. Then I get or send data to `travelAPI.php`, where I send and retrieve data from the database.
When I add a trip or an activity; I empty the whole list, then I retrieve all the trips and activities again from the DB.

**In my local environment, everything works fine.** But when I tried to put it online, it's a mess. SQL requests work fine, but my trips list doesn't update, and I don't understand why. Actually, the list seems to refresh, but with the same results, and without the trip I just added. (But the trip is pushed into the database)
To display the new trip, I need to clear Google Chrome cache.

I tried to analyse this issue with Postman extension, but it seems to come from the client side.

**Ajax request:**

```
function insertTrip() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'travelAPI.php?call=insertTrip',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            cityName: $("input[name=cityName]").val(),
            date: $("input[name=date]").val(),
            dateUpdatePlace: $.now()
        },
        success: function() {
            initTripList();
        }
    });
};
```

**initTripList method:**

```
function initTripList() {
    $("#tripList").html('');
    var listPlace = new Array();

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "travelAPI.php?call=getTrips",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                if (i === 0) {
                    $("#tripList").append('<div class="trip" data-id="' + data[i].idPlace + '"><div class="headingName"><p class="tripName">' + data[i].namePlace + '</p><img class="editNameAction" src="imgs/edit.png" width="30px" alt="edit"></div><div class="editName" style="display:none"><input type="text" name="tripName" value="Text to edit"><img class="confirmEditName" src="imgs/validate.png" width="30px" alt="valider"></div><p class="tripDate">' + data[i].datePlace + '</p><div class="editDate" style="display:none"><input type="text" name="tripDate" value="Text to edit"><img class="confirmEditDate" src="imgs/validate.png" width="30px" alt="valider"></div><ul><li data-id="' + data[i].idActivity + '"><a href="#">' + data[i].nameActivity + '</a><img class="deleteActivity" src="imgs/delete.png" style="width: 15px;"></li></ul></div>');
                } else {
                    if ($.inArray(data[i].idPlace, listPlace) != -1) {
                        $('.trip[data-id="' + data[i].idPlace + '"] ul').append('<li data-id="' + data[i].idActivity + '"><a href="#">' + data[i].nameActivity + '</a><img class="deleteActivity" src="imgs/delete.png" style="width: 15px;"></li>');
                    } else {
                        $("#tripList").append('<div class="trip" data-id="' + data[i].idPlace + '"><div class="headingName"><p class="tripName">' + data[i].namePlace + '</p><img class="editNameAction" src="imgs/edit.png" width="30px" alt="edit"></div><div class="editName" style="display:none"><input type="text" name="tripName" value="Text to edit"><img class="confirmEditName" src="imgs/validate.png" width="30px" alt="valider"></div><p class="tripDate">' + data[i].datePlace + '</p><div class="editDate" style="display:none"><input type="text" name="tripDate" value="Text to edit"><img class="confirmEditDate" src="imgs/validate.png" width="30px" alt="valider"></div><ul><li data-id="' + data[i].idActivity + '"><a href="#">' + data[i].nameActivity + '</a><img class="deleteActivity" src="imgs/delete.png" style="width: 15px;"></li></ul></div>');
                    }
                }
                listPlace.push(data[i].idPlace);
            }
        }
    });
    setTimeout(function() {
        initTripListSec();
    }, 100);
};
```

Comment: initTripList method is at the end of my file :
https://jsfiddle.net/h17ufjLe/

It's a little messy, but it's my display logic.

Comment: Though if it is a caching issue, you might look at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ for the `cache` option and try setting that to false and see if anything changes for you

Comment: Ooooh it works !I add cache: false to all my Ajax requests & it just works fine !Thanks a lot, I was on it since yesterday :)

Comment: And here I am, reading the code seeing the fix (without reading the comments) and still I couldn't resist on making a remark on `initTripList`, `insertTrip` and `call=getTrips` in a different context. However to stay on topic, you should not create and insert a full blown element as its not dynamic and really is just static. While CSS has somewhat control over it nothing else does. A proper code only inserts the a specific `li` or perhaps even `span` element in this case.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But the content is enterily dynamic :)